# Import File Activity Automation - Change field data type to match Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, data-import

I am setting up a File Import automation to ingest a file from the Marketing Cloud FTP to a Data Extension. I am running into an issue where the csv has a field for a newsletter preference say 'Newsletter1' with a text value of 'X' (X represents something like a checkmark/boolean in this case).

Is there a way to change this value, currently 'X', to 'TRUE', such that it matches the data type of the corresponding data extension I have set up? Else, the iport activity will fail.

I'm assuming I may need to either import the data to another data extension and then use a SQL activity to change the 'X' to a boolean value using a case statement, but was hoping there was another work around as to not create 2 data extensions for one import.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Isn't it easier if you change the field value in the CSV file to Boolean value before putting it into FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two ways of doing this:

1. Update the value in the system exporting the data to the CSV
2. Import into a data extension with field type Text, and use SQL to process the value into the right format and upsert it into your actual target data extension.

Unfortunately the File Import activity is not capable of doing any data operations on the data received from the CSV file.